# How do I make multiple gauge charts in C3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I want to put multiple gauge charts in a `div`, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Here's `index.html`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>U.S. presidential vote, 1972-2016, by race</title>

    <!-- Load c3.css -->
    <link href="css/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Load d3.js and c3.js -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/c3.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var dataDir = "vote-by-race";
        d3.csv(dataDir+"/white.csv").then(function(data){
            data.forEach(function(d,i){
                var chartDiv = document.createElement("div");
                chartDiv.id = "chart"+i;
                chartDiv.setAttribute("display","inline-block");
                document.getElementById("charts-container").appendChild(chartDiv);

                var chart = c3.generate({
                    data: {
                        json: d
                    },
                    type: "gauge",
                    bindto: '#'+chartDiv.id
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="charts-container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the CSV I'm working with.

```
YEAR,DEMOCRAT,REPUBLICAN,OTHER
1972,32,66,2
1976,47,52,1
1980,35,56,9
1984,35,64,1
1988,40,59,1
1992,39,40,21
1996,43,46,11
2000,42,54,4
2004,41,58,1
2008,43,55,2
2012,39,59,2
2016,37,58,5
```

But when I open the HTML file in a browser, I see this.
[image]

How do I make a gauge chart for each row of data? I want each gauge chart (each year) to show the portions for Dems, GOP, and other.

Comment: add a new `div` for each gauge needed and set the display style of these to `inline-block`. How do you connect the example gauge to the `div#chart`?

Comment: @rioV8 How would such code look?

Comment: give the divs `id`s like `c0`, `c1`,... and bind to this `id` name, the foreach give you an index if you want.

Comment: the `type` is part of the `data` object and the `bindto` needs a `#` char. How can the class be `gauge-chart` when you set it to `chart`?

Comment: @rioV8 Updated my question

Comment: you haven't applied my first remark

Comment: @rioV8 Which one? Can you post an answer showing how my code should look?

Comment: the piece of text **before** "and"

Comment: Thanks. I edited the code again to reflect your suggestion. The gauge charts show up, but look more like rainbows. That's a separate issue for me to work on, though. If you'd like credit for your answer, feel free to post one and I'll check it off.

Comment: maybe you need a `pie` or a `donut` chart, or any other chart type see the examples